# Question has much higher identifier number than expected

Tags: support, questions, post-id

Yesterday a question was posted at the [Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com) that ticked the question counter at https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions over to 3,000.

With a number of questions having been deleted from our site I expected that the identifier for this question would probably be somewhere a little over 3,000 and was surprised to see that its identifier is 15,990: [Baptism record from Plymouth, MA - 1925](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/15990/baptism-record-from-plymouth-ma-1925) (`https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/15990/baptism-record-from-plymouth-ma-1925`)

I am sure that we are not deleting 80% of our questions.

Were the question identifier counters moved forward at some point(s) in the past?

Comment: Afaik that counter is used for all posts, not just questions. If you create a URL with an ID for an answer, even when using "question" in it, it will lead to that answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That ID is used for questions, answers, but also for other post types like [tag wikis, tag excerpts and moderator nominations](https://data.stackexchange.com/genealogy/query/1163128). (Help Center articles are posts too but are [stored in another database](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345281/4751173).)

Still, even counting deleted ones, you have [slightly less than 10,000 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/genealogy/query/1163125). [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/genealogy/query/1163124) shows the counters were moved forward more than once:

- from ~300 to ~1300
- from ~4200 to ~5200
- from ~5500 to ~6500
- from ~6800 to ~7800
- from ~8100 to ~9100
- from ~10700 to ~11700

I'm curious to know why that happened but SEDE doesn't tell me. I can imagine that site merges would cause some gaps, but I doubt your site has had six of them.

The total number of questions (including deleted ones) is [a little over 3,400](https://data.stackexchange.com/genealogy/query/1163127), so about 10% has been deleted, which is indeed much lower than 80%.

Comment: Thanks for investigating this and answering.  We've had no site merges so I think the "thousand gaps" must be related to the answer on the duplicate.

Comment: I 100% agree with the duplicate closure. Interesting to see how it works under the hood...

Comment: These gaps are *probably* related to the way SQL Server manages identity columns (the column that contains the auto-generated Id), see https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/106220/72163 for details, TL;DR: Various events, like rebooting a SQL Server can cause ID columns to skip 1,000 values